# Java: Is there any way to run a method of a class that initialized the instance of the class from which I want to run it?

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I'm using the JMS (Java Messaging System) to test a standard application between a Client and a Server.

The application is divided by layers, in the client module, I have 3 different files, there is the Main which is like the application itself, the file of the controller that has a ListView with the list of messages and finally the third file that basically is the one that is responsible for sending and receiving incoming messages.

As it is divided into layers, when I start the application, the Controller starts an instance of the Messaging class, so that it can send the messages that are written in the interface and of course store them in the ListView that I have with all message history.

The question is the following, when I send a message, it passes it from the controller to the class of the messaging so it could be sent to the server, but when I do the reverse process, that the messaging receives a new message, I can not find the way to pass it back to the controller, since the controller was the one who initiated the messaging instance and not the other way around.

THE CONTROLLER LOOKS THIS WAY:

```
public class LoanClientController implements Initializable{

public ApplicationGateway applicationGateway = new ApplicationGateway(){};

public TextField tfSsn;
public TextField tfAmount;
public TextField tfTime;

public ListView<ListViewLine> lvLoanRequestReply;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    tfSsn.setText("123456");
    tfAmount.setText("80000");
    tfTime.setText("30");
}

@FXML
public void btnSendLoanRequestClicked() throws Exception {

    int ssn = Integer.parseInt(tfSsn.getText());
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(tfAmount.getText());
    int time = Integer.parseInt(tfTime.getText());
    LoanRequest loanRequest = new LoanRequest(ssn,amount,time);
    ListViewLine listViewLine = applicationGateway.sendMessage(loanRequest);

    lvLoanRequestReply.getItems().add(listViewLine);
    applicationGateway.setLvLoanRequestReply(lvLoanRequestReply);
    lvLoanRequestReply.refresh();

}
}
```

ON THE OTHER SIDE, THE APPLICATION GATEWAY a.k.a. "MESSAGING CLASS" is the following:

```
public class ApplicationGateway implements MessageListener {

public MessagingGateway messagingGateway = new MessagingGateway("Client-Broker", "Broker-Client");

public ApplicationGateway(){

    try {
        messagingGateway.getConsumer().setMessageListener(this);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

   try {

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                LoanReply loanReply = gson.fromJson(((TextMessage) message).getText(), LoanReply.class);


    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is when a new message arrives via the onMessage method, send the value to the Controller.

Comment: Tip about Stack Overflow: Source code in the Question must be indented four spaces to be marked as such. Before copy-pasting, use your source editor to indent selected code. I half-fixed it for you here, but not fully.

Comment: You have a JavaFX client and you are also using the _Spring_ framework. Perhaps these details will help attract people to your question. Feel free to edit your question and include these details.

Comment: you can just add `LoanClientController` to the constructor of `ApplicationGateway`, and then pass itself: `new ApplicationGateway(this)`. but you may want to rethink your design since you are creating 2-way coupling between the classes

Comment: @Abra ok, hope that works. Thanks!

Comment: @matanper I've tried it, but it produces a stack overflow error as it's a circular reference. How could I implement the 2-way coupling trying to avoid that?

Comment: Try adding the relevant code (include the constructors and how you initialize the objects)

Comment: @matanper actually it finally worked with your solution. I though I've made it before, but no. Thank you very much for your help!